# How to concatenate multiple videos including the original audio using opencv in python?

Tags: python, opencv, audio, video, concatenation

As it says on in the title, the task i am trying to accomplish is relatively simple to understand but has been a bit of a pain trying to implement.

I regularly record videos which I post to various social media platforms, however different platforms will only accept uploads of certain sizes, (1 min for some, 10 mins for others, etc...) As the videos I record are mostly done off the cuff I rarely pay attention to how long i'm recording for and often overshoot the time limits. Previously I have always just manually trimmed the videos and uploaded them seperately, but this is obviously time consuming and I know is a task that can be done by a program specifically written for that purpose. I know that there are many paid closed source programs which can accomplish this task, but I thought i'd have a go at writing my own.

I have successfully completed the code to the point where I can invoke the script from command line and it will indeed output a concatenated video file at the end, HOWEVER, the code that i have written will only output a video file with none of the accompanying audio from each file it used to create the merged output.

I have tried in vain to adjust the code accordingly in order to get the result I want, but am continually coming up against issues. Although I fully understand the concepts behind writing code, I am fairly new to opencv and not quite familiar with all of the commands and modules which it contains and so am stuck at this point.

I am aware that this task could possibly be accomplished by using ffmpeg, but I would like to avoid using this if possible as my overall aim is to go on to create the reverse of the concatenation script in python to then be able to split the merged output into smaller chunks which I can specify at runtime. I am hoping that with a python script I will be able to package both of these modules together and be able to achieve a merge and then resplit using just one call to the script, rather than having to call the functions separately.

I attach the code below and invite assistance from anyone who has been able to overcome the problem I am currently having. Thanks in advance.

```
import os
import cv2
import time
import sys

def merge_videos(directory):
    # get all video files from the given directory
    video_files = []
    for file in os.listdir(directory):
        if file.endswith(".mp4"):
            video_files.append(os.path.join(directory, file))

    # read in each video file and extract date and time from the file name
    video_data = []
    for file_path in video_files:
        file_name = os.path.basename(file_path)
        date_time = file_name.split("_")[0]
        video_data.append({"file_path": file_path, "date_time": date_time})

    # sort the video files in date/time order
    sorted_video_data = sorted(video_data, key=lambda x: x["date_time"])

    # create a video writer object to merge the videos
    frame_size = None
    fps = None
    video_writer = None
    audio_codec = None
    audio_fps = None

    # initialize progress bar variables
    total_frames = 0
    current_frame = 0
    start_time = time.time()

    for data in sorted_video_data:
        # read in the video file
        video = cv2.VideoCapture(data["file_path"])

        # get frame size and fps from the first video file
        if frame_size is None:
            frame_size = (int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH)),
                          int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT)))
        if fps is None:
            fps = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

        # get audio codec properties
        if audio_codec is None:
            audio_codec = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FOURCC))
        if audio_fps is None:
            audio_fps = int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FPS))

        # calculate total frames in the video
        total_frames += int(video.get(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_COUNT))

        # initialize the video writer
        if video_writer is None:
            output_path = os.path.join(directory, "merged_videos.mp4")
            video_fourcc = cv2.VideoWriter_fourcc(*"mp4v")
            video_writer = cv2.VideoWriter(output_path, video_fourcc, fps, frame_size, True)

        # read each frame and write it to the output video
        while video.isOpened():
            ret, frame = video.read()
            if ret:
                # add audio to the video writer
                audio_frame = video.read()[1]
                if audio_frame is not None:
                    video_writer.write(audio_frame)

                video_writer.write(frame)

                current_frame += 1

                # update progress bar
                progress = current_frame / total_frames
                bar_length = 50
                filled_length = int(round(bar_length * progress))
                remaining_time = (time.time() - start_time) * (total_frames / current_frame - 1)
                eta = time.strftime("%H:%M:%S", time.gmtime(remaining_time))
                bar = "#" * filled_length + "-" * (bar_length - filled_length)
                sys.stdout.write(f"\r|{bar}| {current_frame}/{total_frames} [{progress:.2%}] ETA: {eta}")
                sys.stdout.flush()
            else:
                break

        # release the video object
        video.release()

    # release the video writer object
    video_writer.release()
```

Although I was at a point where I was easily able to output a concatenated video, after making adjustments to address the audio issue, the code above does no longer seems to be working as it should and now the videos will not seem to concatenate properly and when trying to concatenate just two videos, an error is thrown after the first video file has finished processing at 50% progress..

The console output is the following;

```
|#########################-------------------------| 4347/8694 [50.00%] ETA: 00:03:28[mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2 @ 00000210d0ec4600] moov atom not found
```

Having researched this error, I understand it to be associated with file corruption, but the original files are uncorrupted and still play as they should with full audio.

If anyone could also shed light on this issue alongside the audio issue, I would be most grateful.

Comment: As far as I know OpenCV doesn't support audio (maybe there is some [new feature](https://opencv.org/opencv-4-5-5/) *"Audio support in videoio module (MSMF and GStreamer backends)"*) ... I suggest you to use FFmpeg with segment muxer. When segmenting with FFmpeg there is an option to create a text file (with list) to be used with concat demuxer for merging the segments. Add `-reset_timestamps 1` flag for making the playable clips.

Comment: Maybe try FFmpeg and see if the error persists

Comment: Thank you both, Rotem and code-lukas. I appreciate your answers and quick responses. Although not quite the solutions that I wanted. I did suspect that the cause of no audio would be that OpenCV had no support for audio files, but after looking at the same  documentation that you have also pointed me to, I assumed (obviously incorrectly) that  audio support was an existing feature but found no proper instructions on how to use such feature in my program. Hence why I have posed the question here. Am grateful for the clarification and guess that i'm going to have to go back to the drawing board